# (VB.NET Visual Studio 2019) How can I make a parent/child database work through multiple forms?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2019, parent-child

I am creating forms in Visual Studio 2019 (using VB.Net) that is connected to a Microsoft Access Database.

From the image below, I have a parent form (i.e., Customer Database) with a key ID that is Customer Address. When I press the purchase history at the bottom, I can open a child form (i.e., Customer Purchase History). However, I do not know the specific code to write in the child form to filter the purchases for the current key ID.

In the example below, when I press "Purchase History", it shows the purchases of all customers and not of 1011 WESTON RD. The code that I currently use says
"Me.TblCustomerPurchaseHistoryTableAdapter.Fill(Me.CustdataDataSet.tblCustomerPurchaseHostory)"

Can anyone help me how to do the filtering for the child database? I will appreciate your help so much. Thank you!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkPsW.jpg)

Comment: Could you share your project on GitHub or provide some related code here? It will help others make a test.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need a parameter to your table adapter. Click on your table adapter and select add query on your child form.

It will prompt out something like
Select Transdate, Customer,Qty,Price from CustomerPurchaseHistory (e.g)
then you add the parameter by extending the query
Select Transdate, Customer,Qty,Price from CustomerPurchaseHistory **Where Customer = @Customer** (e.g) and Name it as FillByCustomer on Top.

A new query will be created.

Then you probably have something like Me.TblCustomerPurchaseHistoryTableAdapter.FillByCustomer(Me.CustdataDataSet.tblCustomerPurchaseHostory, [Pass your customer Code here])

On your sub form
Declare a parameter something like

```
Public CustomerCode as string
```

(So that you can pass the parameter form your parent)
On your parent you can then do something like

```
frmChildform.show
frmChildform.CustomerCode = [Your selected custoemrcode]
```

After that on formload event on your childform just do something like

```
Me.TblCustomerPurchaseHistoryTableAdapter.FillByCustomer(Me.CustdataDataSet.tblCustomerPurchaseHostory, CustomerCode)
```